# How can I add asset/Image to specific folder using Kentico

Tags: kentico-12, kentico-kontent, kentico-api

Currently i am able to add multiple images into kentico.
but how can I add images into specific folder using Kentico API.
I am using Kentico/Kontent-management Package in Node.js project.

Answer (score 1):

I would [retrieve folders](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/management-api-v2#operation/retrieve-asset-folders) and select the one you want (`desiredFolder`) and then when creating asset I would set the `id` (or `extenal_id` if set) to specify to what folder to upload the asset under.

JS SDK should wrap the capabilities of the Kontent REST Management API v2, in this case, the crucial is [folder property of the Asset model](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/management-api-v2#operation/add-an-asset)

```js
const folders = await mClient.listAssetFolders()
  .toPromise(); // get folders
const desiredFolder = folders.items.find(folder => folder.name = "Your delsired folder"); // select desired folder
const assetData = await getAssetDataDataFromUrl(article.image.url)
  .toPromise(); // load binary how you want it
const assetObject = await mClient.uploadBinaryFile().withData(assetData).toPromise(); // upload binary

const asset = await mClient.addAsset()
  .withData({
    descriptions: [{
      language: {
        codename: argv.language
      },
      description: `Image for article ${article.title}`
    }],
    external_id: article.image.id,
    file_reference: {
      ...assetObject.data
    },
    folder:  {
      id: desiredFolder.id,
      // external_id: desiredFolder.externalId // also possible to use external ID
    }
  })
  .toPromise();
```

If you already have the assets in Kontent, you could just update assets to specific folder:

```js
const updatedAsset = await mClient.upsertAsset().withData({
  // not sure if you need to add whole asset object like: `...asset`, but i think it is not necessary
  folder:  {
    id: desiredFolder.id,
    // external_id: desiredFolder.externalId // also possible to use external ID
  }
}).toPromise()
```

> My workflow when creating scripts like that (i.e. [this one](https://github.com/Simply007/kontent-data-generator)) is to take a look to [repo tests](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-management-sdk-js/tree/master/test-browser) in this case these two: [list folders](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-management-sdk-js/blob/master/test-browser/asset-folders/list-asset-folders.spec.ts) and [add assets](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-management-sdk-js/blob/master/test-browser/assets/add-assets.spec.ts). Most of the IDEs (VS Code in my case) should load type definitions and help you with model structure via intellisence.

Comment: I have also added the info to my journal to make it more searchable: https://ondrej.chrastina.tech/journal/specify-folder-when-uploading-asset-via-kontent-js-management-sdk